# flutter error /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/getwidget-2.0.4/lib/components/sticky_header/gf_sticky_header_builder

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, mobile-application

how to solve this error? help!

> /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/getwidget-2.0.4/lib/components/sticky_header/gf_sticky_header_builder.dart:63:28: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
> 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
> package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1
> WidgetsBinding.instance?.endOfFrame.then((_) {

GFStickyHeader flie

````
class _GFStickyHeaderBuilderState extends State<GFStickyHeaderBuilder> {
  double? _stuckValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => GFStickyHeader(
        enableHeaderOverlap: widget.enableHeaderOverlap,
        direction: widget.direction,
        stickyContentPosition: widget.stickyContentPosition,
        stickyContent: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, _) =>
              widget.stickyContentBuilder(context, _stuckValue ?? 0.0),
        ),
        content: widget.content,
        callback: (double stuckValue) {
          if (_stuckValue != stuckValue) {
            _stuckValue = stuckValue;
            WidgetsBinding.instance?.endOfFrame.then((_) {
              if (mounted) {
                setState(() {});
              }
            });
          }
        },
      );
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

- You try upgrade flutter by run flutter upgrade and then run flutter pub cache repair, good luck!